# Kendo Parsing Date

Tags: parsing, datetime, kendo-ui, telerik, date-format

I have custom popup window and it works. Also I am retrieving data from database correctly and binding data. While editing these records from popup whenever date or month is over 12 , there is an error on localhost and says that for example" 12/08/'2011 is not a valid date.
Here is my codes, please help me..

```
@model xxxx.Il

<h3>Customized Il</h3>
<br />
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DegistirenKullanici)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DegistirmeTarihi)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.KayitKullanici)
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IlAdi)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IlAdi)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IlAdi)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KayitTarihi)
    @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.KayitTarihi).Format("dd/mm/yyyy")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KayitTarihi)
</div>
<script>
   kendo.culture("en-GB");
</script>
```

And here is my view cshtml codes;

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@model xxxxx.Il
<section id="gallery">
    <h2 class="ra-well-title">Iller</h2>


    <div>
        <input id='txtIlId' value="" style="width:100%; text-align:center;" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Id'ye göre Arama'" />
        <br>
        <br />
        <input id='txtIlAdi' value="" style="width:100%; text-align:center;" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Ada göre Arama'" />
        <br>
        <br />
    </div>
    <script>
   kendo.culture("en-GB");
    </script>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<xxxx.Il>().Name("Iller")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
        columns.Bound(p => p.IlAdi);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DegistirenKullanici);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DegistirmeTarihi);
        columns.Bound(p => p.KayitKullanici);
        columns.Bound(p => p.KayitTarihi).Format("{0:dd/mm/yyyy}");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(250);
    })
     .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true))
        .Sortable()
        .AutoBind(true)
        .Selectable()
        .Navigatable()
        .Filterable()
        .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("IlModel").Window(w => w.Width(450)).Window(w => w.Title("Düzenle")))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Il_Read", "Tanimlar").Data("getAdditionalData"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Il_Guncelle", "Tanimlar"))
    )
    )
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }


    function onClickBul(e) {
        //kendoConsole.log("event :: click (" + $(e.event.target).closest(".k-button").attr("id") + ")");
        $('#Iller').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    }
    $('#txtIlAdi').keyup(function () {
        $('#Iller').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    });

    function getAdditionalData(e) {
        return {
            //iMrpId: 2
            Iladi: $('#txtIlAdi').val()
        };
    }


</script>
```

Comment: have you tried to parse it as well?

Comment: Yes, I tried all combinations for parsing. But , didnt work

Comment: Ive used it successfully and what I do is add this to my field: format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", parseFormats: ["MM-dd-yyyy"],  and then I use AJAX to bring in my data and I convert it like this: var dateobj = kendo.parseDate(dateReceived);  var datestring = kendo.toString(dateobj, "MM/dd/yyyy"); Try this and see if it works

Comment: thank u very much, tried but not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way how I get a kendo calendar date.

```
var selectedDate = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate($("#diningCalendar").data("kendoCalendar").current()), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

use `kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate())`

Hope this helps.